# Executing Shell Script by adding env variables

Tags: bash, shell, unix, hadoop, hive

```
#!/bin/bash
export HIVE_OPTS="$HIVE_OPTS -hiveconf mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology"
export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/home/hadoop/lib/HiveUDF.jar
hive -S -e 'set mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology'
hive -S -e 'SELECT count(*) from testingtable2' > attachment.txt
```

Whenever I try to run the above shell script(count.sh) like below, I always get errors, I have no idea what wrong I am doing as I am new to shell script and I am not sure how I can add environment variables in shell script.

```
bash-3.00$ sh count.sh
count.sh: HIVE_OPTS= -hiveconf mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology^M: is not an
identifier
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing in my shell script, by the way I am adding environment variables in first two lines? Any help will be appreciated.

After all the changes I did as per the below comments,

```
mv count.sh count, 
chmod +x count, 
./count
```

whenever I try to do this in my prompt directly `export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/home/hadoop/lib/HiveUDF.jar` it works fine, but whenever I try to add this in my shell script as mentioned in my question, I always get 'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File file:/home/hadoop/lib/HiveUDF.jar does not exist. Why is it so?

Comment: 1) You may have DOS line endings in your file, which you can remove using `dos2unix`. 2) What is `email.sh`?

Comment: sorry it was by mistake, it is `count.sh` And what do you mean by DOS line endings?

Comment: `mv count.sh count`, `chmod +x count`, `./count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You edited your shell script on a DOS or Windows machine, which uses the CRLF pair (`\r\n`) instead of the Unix-style LF ('\n') line endings.

The `^M` is the tell-tale -- it is a `\r` carriage return character.

This should fix it:

```
tr -d '\r' < count.sh > count.sh.fixed
mv count.sh.fixed count.sh
```

Another option:

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' count.sh
```

Comment: I tried the first option it worked fine, and that error went away, but I got another error `bash-3.00$ sh email.sh
email.sh: HIVE_OPTS= -hiveconf mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology: is not an identifier`, So anything wrong in the syntax by the way I am adding environment variables?

Comment: That `export HIVE_OPTS="$HIVE_OPTS -..."` worked in my `bash`, `dash`. In my `zsh`, it prepended a space (which I expected -- I'm surprised `bash` and `dash` did not.) [Stephen's advice about executing the program using `bash` as the shebang line directs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680020/executing-shell-script-by-adding-env-variables/11680054#comment15484525_11680020) _may_ help, if your shell does not allow this.

Comment: I tried that also, whenever I try to do this in my prompt `export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/home/hadoop/lib/HiveUDF.jar` it works, but whenever I try to add this in my shell script as mentioned in my question, I always get `'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File file:/home/hadoop/lib/HiveUDF.jar does not exist.` Why is it so?

Comment: What happens with `ls -l /home/hadoop/lib/HiveUDF.jar`?

Comment: Ok.. When I do like this `bash-3.00$ ls -l home/hadoop/lib/HiveUDF.jar
home/hadoop/lib/HiveUDF.jar: No such file or directory` I get `No Such File` Strange? :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the leading `/` when I first copied-and-pasted that string. Try again with the leading `/`.

Comment: I tried again and same result. `bash-3.00$ ls -l /home/hadoop/lib/HiveUDF.jar
/home/hadoop/lib/HiveUDF.jar: No such file or directory`. But if I go to bash prompt and hit this directly `bash-3.00$ export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/home/hadoop/lib/HiveUDF.jar`. I don't get any error.

Comment: That's because your `export` command is only setting an environment variable. You could just as well run `export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=rjchar_rules_the_world` and it wouldn't complain. You'll need to find the _actual_ path to your `HiveUDF.jar` file, and use that in your `export` command.

Comment: So my syntax is fine as per the shell scripting goes if you need to set any environment variables?

Comment: Well, it's fine on _my_ shells; as Alan points out above, it might not work on all shells. If you're still executing the script with `sh email.sh`, then your `sh` might not work. But if you use `./email.sh`, you should get `bash`, and I believe all versions of `bash` support `export` on the same line as the assignment.

Comment: hmmm, I started doing from the fresh, and now I am getting this error `bash-3.00$ ./email.sh
: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` Any idea? what's wrong?

Comment: Now, `ls -l /bin/bash`. I bet you don't have `bash` installed under the name `/bin/bash`. What kind of system _are_ you on? Maybe it'd be far easier to write a new tool directly intended to fix the thing you've got.

Comment: `bash-3.00$ ls -l /bin/bash
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root     bin       611132 May  2  2007 /bin/bash
`. I am connected to one of the machine using Putty as I am working with Hive.

Comment: The bad interpreter is a sign that there is still a ^M on the shebang line

Comment: @Alan: Ha! Man, I never would have found that again. At this point I assumed that was solved. :)

Comment: @rjchar: are you continuing to edit this file with a _Windows_ text editor? If so, save yourself a few hundred hours of hassles and give up on that and learn `vi` or `emacs`. Or, at least, `nano`. (`nano` is so feature-deficient that it would never be my first choice of an editor, but it might be way easier to use tonight than learning `vi` or `emacs`.)

Comment: hmmm, somethign strange going on, When I tried doing like this `bash email.sh` I get exception as `File Not Found Exception` now. But when I try to do like this `./email.sh` I get `permission denied error`. So both the syntax are same in the way of executing shell script?

Comment: Sure, I will do that, So which editor is fine to work vi or emacs or nano

Comment: `permission denied` probably means you need to re-run the `chmod 755 email.sh` command. If you've never heard of `vi` or `emacs` before now, use `pico` right now and look into `vi` later. It's too much to do when you're in a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

You're running a bash script with a `sh` command that is not bash. Run it with `./count.sh` so the shebang line will take effect, or just say `bash count.sh`.

Comment: Thanks Alan for the comment, yes by the way you told me I made some progress, but I am getting File Not Found Exception, the only question I have is the way I have added export in first two lines, it should be like that only as far as syntax goes if you are adding any environment variables?

Comment: @rjchar It's valid syntax for bash, and for POSIX sh, but not for some older unix shells, which require the assignment and the export to be done separately. That's why you got the "not an identifier" message when you didn't run it with bash. I don't know why your file is not found now.

Comment: Any idea which shell specifically forces it to be done on two commands?

Comment: @sarnold Currently? I'm not sure. Solaris I'd guess. Historically? Original Bourne shell didn't support export and assignment combined in a single statement. I think that syntax first appeared in the Korn shell, and was adopted into POSIX from there.

Comment: @sarnold ksh is the origin of a lot of features that people take for granted in "sh" scripts now. Like arithmetic. Nobody knows how to use `expr` any more...